# An error with if statement in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script, but it's giving me a syntax error at the following command:

```
if [[ -n ${array[$x1]}  -a [ expr length "$x1" -gt 2 ] ]]
```

This is the error message:

```
./project: line 45: syntax error in conditional expression
./project: line 45: syntax error near `-a'
./project: line 45: `   if [[ -n ${array[$x1]}  -a [ expr length "$x1" -gt 2 ] ]]'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&&` not `-a` in `[[ ]]`

Also, `expr length` won't do what you expect here. The better approach, since you're already using bash extensions, is to use the `${#param}` expansion to get the length of `$param`, and evaluate that within a math context, like so:

```
if [[ -n ${array[$x1]} ]] && (( ${#x1} > 2 )); then
  ...
fi
```

Comment: it's give me the following- :
`
`./project: line 45: conditional binary operator expected

./project: line 45: syntax error near `expr'

./project: line 45: ` if [[ -n ${array[$x1]}  && [ expr length "$x1" -gt 2 ] ]]'`

`

Comment: @user3137879 Right -- `expr length` is wrong too (within `[[ ]]` context), as is use of `[ ]` for grouping inside `[[ ]]`.

Comment: thank you , this problem fixed , but could you tell me what is the wrong/wrongs that i have ? , since i want to learn shell script ?

Comment: @user3137879: Note that `[` is a different test command, not just 'an alternative to parentheses for grouping conditionals'.  You should generally assume that if you're trying to use `expr`, you are doing it wrong; `bash` has essentially eliminated the need to use `expr`.  You'll also need to understand when commands get executed...that was part of the `$(expr ...)` in an answer suggested by someone else (now deleted so you can't see it), but there were other issues in that answer that were not addressed). You should generally use double quotes more liberally, but `[[` is less fussy than most.